# How do I align 3 boxes that are 100% wide to be stacked underneath each?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know this is super simple but not sure why I can't accomplish this.

**What I want to do?**

I want to have 3 boxes that are going to be as wide as the user's screen and they need to be stacked underneath each other.  I also want to remove the whitespace that shows on the left and right.

**What did I try?**

```
<div class="box box1">
</div>
<div class="box box2">
</div>
<div class="box box3">
</div>

.box {
     width: 100%;
     float: left;
     height: 300px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box1 {
     background: red;
}
.box2 {
     background: green;
}
.box3 {
     background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cUhfh/ even though your float and width rules don't seem to go together.

Comment: So simply remove the `float: left;` CSS declaration

Comment: thanks @j08691 but i also need to remove the whitespace on the left and right.  how do i do that? i thought using float will make it completely 100%.

Comment: That is the default behavior for display: block elements such as a div. You don't need width 100%; It will do that on it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not `float` them. `width: 100%` is redundant when You remove `float`.

The whitespace on the sides is probably margin or padding on the `body` element. Just add `body { margin: 0; padding: 0}` to Your CSS.

Comment: Also, if i wanted to remove the space in between the boxes can i use negative margins to move each of them up or is there a better way?

Comment: Then please remove this margin: `.box {margin-bottom: 20px}`

Comment: I did but it still has the space.